# MediaElement wont dispose on fresh install?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Okay, I have this weird bug that I really hope you guys can help me.

I use a MediaElement to show a video, that MediaElement is inside of a StateView.
When I install the App totally fresh it acts very weird, let me try to show with some screenshots:
I put an eventlistener on the media element to show the state of it.

[Here after the fresh install i see the mediaelement plays as it should,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvAwy.png)
now i press our button "Skan QR koden":

[Now i see part of the video showing, in the camera field (sometimes you have to minimize the app and reopen it to make it appear).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFhyP.png)
I have tried to NULL the source of the mediaelement when switching state, nothing seems to kill the player.

Okay but now I close/rebuild the app and run it again:
[The mediaelement is playing the video as it should.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfVL5.png)
I now go to the QR page:

[The media element now stopped as I expected and is not shown partly on the camera view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9gVd.png)

I really have no idea whats going on. Please let me know if i didnt explain it well enough.

This is btw only an Android issue it seems.

Platform Target Frameworks:
Android: 12
Android Support Library Version:
Nuget Packages: XCT 2.0.4 - Xamarin 5.0.0.2515
Affected Devices: Tested on emulators. Huawei P30, different Xiaomi phones.

I tried to create a custom renderer for the mediaelement, and i see in both cases that the Release method gets called, with no errors. But it seems like it only gets released on the 2nd try and not on a fresh install....

We have always struggled with the MediaElement ( we use a lot of tutorial videos) especially using them in a CarouselView ( but we solved those by stopping and/or using Opacity 0 to hide old videos).

Ive tried to null the source, null the media element, But i can still see it "Playing" in the background...

I tried upgrading all my nuget packages, but still the same issue.